# How to share my wireless connection to other wireless devices

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am aware that I can share my wired internet connection to other devices wirelessly, but what I need now is a little more complex. I am limited to one device over the wifi but would like my macbook to have internet as well. It's in another room so ethernet is not really an option. I really would like to share the wireless from my ubuntu (it's on more) to other wireless devices.

After some light googling I can't find anything even remotely useful as they all involve an ethernet cable at some point. Has anyone here had any luck with anything similar?

I am running  12.04 LTS just for reference and have a Belkin G wireless USB device. If anyone knows a possible procedure I can find out about the chipset etc. if needed. I understand there may be hardware limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround although it's not what I was originally after.

Open up a terminal on the first computer **ctrl alt t**

Run **ifconfig -a**

Look for the MAC address following **wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr**

On the other computer, if its a linux run **sudo ifconfig wlan0 down**

then **sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether** *your desired MAC address here*

then run
**sudo ifconfig wlan0 up**

Or if the other computer is running OSX (boo hiss!) like in my case then run 
**sudo ifconfig en1 ether** *your desired MAC address here*

They will both connect appearing as one device. This is called spoofing a MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a router running open-ddwrt or seavsoft even and then use it as your access point.  The way it would only technically connect one device, but you would have your own internal wireless network.

I know wrt54g has this functionality with the custom firmware, but I doubt your laptop has this capability.

I would look at picking up one of these cheap devices it will save you a lot of headaches because its meant to do stuff like this.

http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=wrt54g

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Documentation on how-to setup a repeater bridge - http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

Hope this helps.